# Notification of edit question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

If some one have posted a question on stack exchange site and it's voted to close. Now if the question is improved by editing it, will the people who have voted to close get notification of question being improved, so that they would reconsider vote to reopen ?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: @Siva I [suffered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966371/physical-ram-as-a-file-in-unix) few minutes ago :-)

Answer (score 6):

No, they are not.

However, the Reopen review queue shows posts that are edited after they have been closed, so that appropriate users can look at the question and consider whether it should be reopened.